# Correlated subqueries always raise error, Can't find why

Tags: mysql, sql, database, correlation

Here is may application database tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Cars` (
  `car_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `insertionDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `newCars` (
  `car_id` int(11) NOT NULL, //Only new cars have a dealer (Cars.type = 1)
  `dealer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarsPhotos` (
  `photo_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `car_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `insertionDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`photo_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Dealers` (
  `dealer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dealerName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `insertionDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dealer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dealersPhotos` (
  `photo_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dealer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `insertionDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`photo_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I am trying to find cars that have at least one relevant photo to view (Either car photo or dealer photo) as follows:

1. The search action must be done in one query
2. Check if the car has at least one photo carPhotosCount.
3. if carPhotosCount = 0 Than check if the car is new (Cars.type = 1)
4. If the car is new than get dealer_id from newCars table
5. Check if the dealer has at least one photo dealerPhotosCount.

For that I have written the SQL query (MySQL) in two ways, both of them raise a correlation error.

```
SELECT car_id ,
    FROM Cars c
    WHERE
      CASE
        WHEN
          (SELECT count(*) as carPhotosCount FROM CarsPhotos WHERE CarsPhotos.car_id = c.car_id HAVING carPhotosCount > 0) THEN 1
        ELSE
          CASE
            WHEN type = 1 THEN
              CASE
                WHEN
                  (SELECT count(*) as dealerPhotosCount FROM dealersPhotos
                  JOIN  newCars ON  newCars.car_id = c.car_id
                  WHERE dealersPhotos.dealer_id = newCars.dealer_id HAVING dealerPhotosCount > 0) THEN 1
                ELSE 0
              END
            ELSE 0
          END
      END
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT car_id ,
      CASE
        WHEN type = 1 THEN (SELECT newCars.dealer_id FROM newCars WHERE newCars.car_id = c.car_id)
        ELSE null
      END deal_id
    FROM Cars c
    WHERE
      CASE
        WHEN (SELECT count(*) as dealerPhotosCount FROM dealersPhotos WHERE dealersPhotos.dealer_id = deal_id HAVING dealerPhotosCount > 0) THEN 1
        ELSE
          CASE
            WHEN (SELECT count(*) as carPhotosCount FROM CarsPhotos WHERE CarsPhotos.car_id = c.car_id HAVING carPhotosCount > 0) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
          END
      END
```

Comment: Query 1 must produce syntax error (a comma at the end of output list). In query 2 the condition in HAVING may cause iterations (condition affects on returned rows, this causes new value of the expression in the condition).

Comment: @Adeltaf . . . What error are you getting?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff '   c.car_id' unknown column in ON clause In query 1 - 'deal_id' Unknown Column In Where Clause In query 2

Comment: @ Akina Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `exists` and `limit`:

```
SELECT car_id ,
       (CASE WHEN type = 1
            THEN (SELECT nc.dealer_id FROM newCars nc WHERE nc.car_id = c.car_id LIMIT 1)
        END) as deal_id
FROM Cars c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dealersPhotos dp
              WHERE dp.dealer_id = c.deal_id
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM CarsPhotos cp
              WHERE cp.car_id = c.car_id
             ) ;
```

There is no obvious major error in the queries.  However, the subquery in the `SELECT` could return more than one row and that is would generally result in an error.

EDIT:

You seem to want to join to the dealer in the outer query and then incorporate the logic in the `WHERE` clause.  One method is to repeat the expression in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT c.car_id,
       (CASE WHEN c.type = 1 THEN nc.dealer_id END) as deal_id
FROM Cars c LEFT JOIN
     newCars nc
     ON nc.car_id = c.car_id 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dealersPhotos dp
              WHERE dp.dealer_id = (CASE WHEN c.type = 1 THEN nc.dealer_id END)
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM CarsPhotos cp
              WHERE cp.car_id = c.car_id
             ) ;
```

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff 'c.deal_id' still unknown in where clause

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff '  it works. Thank you for saving  me from changing my database design.